# How to query a fallback document if there's no document available for current locale in Sanity Studio?

Tags: localization, next.js, sanity

I am working on a multi-lingual project. Which has 3 locales en-SG, en-VN, and vi-VN. Among them, en-SG is a default locale.

Is this possible to query the docs in a way so that when there is no doc for any locale(especially en-VN) the site shows the default locale doc?

I have achieved something similar with this query.

`*[_type == "cardPage" && (__i18n_lang == $locale || __i18n_lang == $defaultLocale ) && !(_id in path('drafts.**'))]`

But it's not working properly when the $locale doc available, it's querying the $locale doc and $defaultLocale doc at the same time. And showing the $defaultLocale doc instead of the actual $locale doc on some pages.

I am using nextjs for front end and [sanity-plugin-intl-input](https://github.com/LiamMartens/sanity-plugin-intl-input) plugin for localization.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your default document to your result and return the first match.

```js
[(
  *[ _type == "something" && the_one_you_want ] +
  *[ _type == "something" && fallback_or_default ]
)[0]]
```

There are different flavors of concatenation. Here is another with Spread syntax.

```js
[
  ...*[ _type == "something" && the_one_you_want ],
  ...*[ _type == "something" && fallback_or_default ]
][0]
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Save me some time. Important to note, you can still open a projection `{}` directly after the code above.